# Mocking html-pdf using Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I am using the [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) package in my nodejs code (not in Typescript). Now, this package has a `create()` function which is chained with the `toBuffer()` function. I am unit testing my code using Jest and want to mock this call `pdf.create(html).toBuffer()`.

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(htmlToPdfError, buffer){
  if (htmlToPdfError) {
    reject(htmlToPdfError);
  }
  resolve(buffer.toString('base64'));
});
```

EDIT:
I am trying to use the following code in my spec file to make the module:

```
jest.mock('html-pdf', () => ({
    create: jest.fn(() => {
        return Promise.resolve();
    })
}));
```

This is helping me mock the `create()` function but I do not know how to return a object in Promise.resolve which would have a `toBuffer` function

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @MattMorgan it tried using this in my test cases:
    ```jest.mock('html-pdf', () => ({
        create: jest.fn(() => {
            return Promise.resolve();
        })
    }));
```
But this is just mocking the `create()` function. I am not able to mock the `toBuffer()`

Comment: Please add that information to your question.

Comment: @MattMorgan updated

Comment: I am curious why you need to mock this at all.. you are running your unit tests on a machine that doesn't have whatever phantomjs dependencies are needed to run html-pdf?  Or you just want to make sure you always get the same answer?

Comment: or to speed up your tests?

Answer (score 1):

I could mock it using the following code:

```
const mockToBuffer = {
    toBuffer: jest.fn((callback: Function) => callback(null, null)),
}

jest.mock('html-pdf', () => ({
    create: jest.fn(() => mockToBuffer),
}))

it('Should work', async () => {
    const expectedResult = Buffer.from([10])

    mockToBuffer.toBuffer.mockImplementation((callback: Function) => {
        callback(null, expectedResult)
    })

    // const result = await yourFuncUsingHtmlPdf(/* fakePayload */)

    // Comparing the buffer using the native function
    // expect(expectedResult.equals(result)).toBe(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

and then assert that your "pdf" buffer contains "test string"?

```
jest.mock('html-pdf', () => ({
  create: jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      toBuffer: function(callback) {
        callback(null, Buffer.from("test string", "utf-8"));
      },
    });
  })
}));
```

(I haven't tried it)